# MongoDB 2dsphere index fails (malformed geometry?)

Tags: mongodb, geojson, mongodb-indexes, 2dsphere

I'm currently trying to build an 2dsphere index, but the creation seems to fail.

The document on which the index creation fails is valid geojson (according to geojsonlint).

Also as far as I can see it obeys the MongoDB "Polygon" rules.

I would appreciate any help, since I can't figure out why the index creation seems to fail.

Thanks in advance!

```
db.poly.ensureIndex( { loc: "2dsphere" } )
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?: { _
id: 353, loc: { type: \"Polygon\", coordinates: [ [ [ 8.090732000000001, 53.6379
766 ], [ 8.050639500000001, 53.6250853 ], [ 8.036974600000001, 53.6286108 ], [ 7
.994035500000001, 53.6016978 ], [ 8.0120927, 53.59855020000001 ], [ 8.0102720000
00001, 53.5883803 ], [ 8.023379, 53.5867745 ], [ 8.0148004, 53.5832729 ], [ 8.02
6839500000001, 53.57895840000001 ], [ 8.0271685, 53.5727671 ], [ 8.0432450000000
01, 53.57190120000001 ], [ 8.0386477, 53.565241 ], [ 8.0192488, 53.5609644 ], [
8.030192100000001, 53.5508096 ], [ 8.037298, 53.5565769 ], [ 8.041402400000001,
53.55249540000001 ], [ 8.030647100000001, 53.53854200000001 ], [ 8.0381080000000
01, 53.5275022 ], [ 8.048501400000001, 53.5243656 ], [ 8.051459700000001, 53.509
912 ], [ 8.091510100000001, 53.50258460000001 ], [ 8.153839000000001, 53.5148059
0000001 ], [ 8.1708242, 53.53993010000001 ], [ 8.164240300000001, 53.5287913 ],
[ 8.1562255, 53.531339 ], [ 8.1700993, 53.54524050000001 ], [ 8.150740200000001,
 53.5596328 ], [ 8.1539377, 53.56452330000001 ], [ 8.1408203, 53.58015880000001
], [ 8.155694800000001, 53.5858101 ], [ 8.1496093, 53.60191990000001 ], [ 8.1234
503, 53.5984032 ], [ 8.090732000000001, 53.6379766 ] ] ] } }",
        "code" : 16755
}
```

Comment: To I understanding you should make index on `loc.coordinates`. but why are there so many nested arrays in field `coordinates`?

Comment: can you share your schema and example document? that would help debug this.

Comment: The document basically just consists of the "loc" property. So the schema is visible in the above error message

Comment: just for the record, I had an issue with coordinates format while importing from csv geonames dump. The numbers needed to be parsed as float. As for your issue, maybe you could check if your polygones are intersecting each others? which is not valid

Comment: There was an intersection, but I couldn't see it because it wasn't obvious!

Comment: If you want to spot mistakes in your GeoJSON objects I can recommend http://geojsonlint.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an intersection in the coordinates, but I couldn't see it through geojsonlint.com because it wasn't obvious!

MongoDB doesn't allow inserting a polygon which lines would intersect.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the index to "loc" (the GeoJSON field) as you have done. However, make sure that your coordinates are specified in the order of **Longitude, Latitude** (not **Latitude, Longitude**).

Per the documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#spherical:

> Store your location data as GeoJSON objects with this coordinate-axis
>   order: longitude, latitude. The coordinate reference system for
>   GeoJSON uses the WGS84 datum.

Also, per the GeoJSON spec at http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions:

> A position is represented by an array of numbers. There must be at
>   least two elements, and may be more. The order of elements must follow
>   x, y, z order (easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a
>   projected coordinate reference system, or longitude, latitude,
>   altitude for coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system).
>   Any number of additional elements are allowed -- interpretation and
>   meaning of additional elements is beyond the scope of this
>   specification.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur if you have multiple documents in your collection and at least one document among them is having the 'loc' field as NULL OR EMPTY.

So make sure you don't have any document where 'loc' field is NULL OR EMPTY.

Query: db.poly.find("loc":{$exists:true, $eq:""});

Note:
You need to add the Index to 'loc' field, not for 'loc.coordinates' field.

Answer (score -2):

So the solution would be simply building index on `loc.coordinates` instead of `loc`

```
db.coor.ensureIndex({"loc.coordinates": "2dsphere"})
```

Note 2d index supports different format, which you can find examples in the [document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#multi-location-documents-for-2d-indexes). While `loc` is not one of them.

I don't understand why you have nested array there though.

Comment: In my understanding I need to create the index on the "loc" field. Its a nested array because accordingly to the geojson Format this is a valid geojson object. See [mongodb polygon](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#polygon)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You need to put the index on the GeoJSON object, not on the array with coordinates.

Comment: For deep check it out https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/